# Changing the database structure

Tags: c#, database-design

I have a MVC4 application where employees can order lunch. The shoppinglist is then available for the person who goes to the supermarket that day. An administrator can settle the costs made each month with a salary. The central order model looks like this:

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; } 
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public bool IsConfirmed { get; set; }
    public bool IsSettledWithSalary { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

This table stores the orders for every product that is ordered. The order does have a quantity for when people order more than one product, but in general it becomes a long table of orders and products.

As can be seen there are two booleans in this table. An `IsConfirmed` and `IsSettledWithSalary` property. This is because people can make an order (`IsConfirmed=false`, `IsSettledWithSalary=false`), which can then be checked with what was available in the supermarket and the actual price (`IsConfirmed=true`, `IsSettledWithSalary=false`) and then finally the same orders can be put settled with salary by an admin (`IsConfirmed=true`, `IsSettledWithSalary=true`).

This last step now consists of adding a product called `Transaction` and setting the price to a negative value so that the balance of the user goes back to 0 and stores it in another `Transaction` table that looks like this:

```
public class Transaction
{
    public int TransactionId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public decimal TransactionAmount { get; set; }
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

That gives an overview.

I did start with the project with this idea in mind of storing negative Transactions products, but looking back I think there might be more elegant solutions.

A friend suggested that I should be using more than one table for orders. Or use a table that links more two different tables together.

I have no clear idea how to do this though and considering the fact that it is not slow as it is, and it works, I would love to hear your thoughts on the database structure as it is and receive advice on how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current situation allows only one type of `Product` to be bought per order. It is highly unlikely that this is something you'd want. You should look at adding a table in between:

Order

- Date
- `List<OrderDetails>`
- ...

OrderDetails

- OrderDetailsId
- OrderId
- ProductId
- UnitPrice
- Quantity

OrderToOrderDetails

- OrderId
- OrderDetailsId

In essence this would mean an extra 1-N table that will keep track of the products inside an order. A separate `Transaction` class might not even be necessary anymore since stuff like `OrderDate`, `PaidDate`, `ReceivedDate` can all be stored inside `Order` (or `OrderDetails`, should you wish to send orders separately).

Comment: And how about extra "in-between tables" (or "koppeltabellen" as they are called in your language)? Do you see an opportunity or advantage for implementing those?

Comment: Or is this OrderOverview table exactly that? :)

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean with this: `In essence this would mean an extra 1-N table that will keep track of the products inside an order.`. You will need such a table to hold these two fields: `OrderId` and `OrderDetailsId` (there should be a primary key here as well, I'll edit it for clarity).